# How to make the .proto definition files visible in Android view in Android Studio (4.2)?

Tags: android, android-studio, protocol-buffers, grpc, android-studio-4.2

When using protobuf definitions in my gradle projects, `protoc` works as expected. Everything builds as it is supposed to do. However, when working in the Android view (I mean **View->Project->Android**), the definition file doesn't show up. On the contrary, it is visible from  **View->Project->Project**. There I can find the my protobuf definition files as expected in e.g. `app/src/main/proto`.

Sources are defined in my `build.gradle` like this:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            proto {
                srcDir '../src/main/proto'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to make the proto source files visible in the Android view?

Comment: Have you seen: [IntelliJ - Set file type associations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html)

Comment: Sorry for disturbing after long time but have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to simply bookmark the .proto files, doing this doesn't make the .proto files appear in your "Android" view but at least you don't have to switch to "Project" view to find those files.